# How to get anchor tag click event in angular 4/5 component without using ng-click on each anchor tag

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I've tried using @HostListener. But it works for clicks general.

```
@HostListener('click') onClick() {
    window.alert('Host Element Clicked');
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to get event element

Comment: yes ..........................

Comment: the have already answered

Comment: do you have any better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you may try using the `currentTarget` to check if the click is from an anchor or not

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget); // You can put this as a IF condition 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great!.. Can you please mark this answered then? :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that imperatively

```
@ViewChild('a') anchor:ElementRef; 

clickHandler(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
_clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.anchor.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', this._clickHandler); 
}
```

to unsubscribe use

```
this.anchor.nativeElement.removeEventListener('click', this._clickHandler);
```

Comment: Most of the libraries are dependent on the ElementRef, Please share the link, I would like to read.

Comment: https://medium.com/@kmathy/angular-manipulate-properly-the-dom-with-renderer-16a756508cba

Comment: Okay, but please read it carefully, this is for manipulation not for listeners