# HostListener and click event is not triggered on links

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, events, listener

I'm looking for the code improvement, why this code

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
onClck(target) {
  console.log(target);
}
```

is not getting triggered on links (a href).
I need it to be triggered on ANY  link and any `<button>` clicks (both by mouse and by keyboard).

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51324537/8351493

Answer (score 0):

Where do you paste this decorator.
Because if you want to get all click in your app. paste decorator in your main component. But If you want to get click anyway in your browser, you need vanilla code:

> document.body.onclick = e => console.log(e);

Comment: It's pasted in the main component.

Comment: do you have try whithout "document:"? Just click?